# Can Barbarians use 2 two-handed weapons in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Can barbarians dual wield two-handed weapons?

My barbarian character is only a level 50 now, but I'm not sure if I can dual wield two-handed weapons at a later level or not - or is there a special skill I need?

**UPDATE**
It is sweet, that Blizzard have finally updated Diablo 3, so that the Crusader can have a 2-handed weapon in 1 hand ([Heavenly Strength](http://www.diablowiki.net/Crusader_skills#Passives) passive). It is a shame that the Crusader can't dual wield a 2-handed weapon in both hands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, barbarians can not dual wield 2 handed weapons nor can they wield 2 handed weapons in 1 hand.

There was a glitch before where this was possible but it has since then been patched and removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is strange as they could dual wield them in Diablo 2.

Comment: The addition of Mighty Weapons is Blizzard's way of improving their item balancing capabilities while still giving the barb the ability to use weapons that are bigger and heavier compared to other classes.  The problem with dual wielding two-handed swords in Diablo 2 was either you made them too powerful for barb or too weak for everyone else.  In essense, the two handed sword was only useable by barb.  In Diablo 3, two handers are balanced well for all classes.